Is it possible to simplify my "always open" H-bridge modification?
I am driving a speaker with a single mosfet and a tone function from Arduino library that generates a tone on a single pin. I want it to be louder, and it occurred to me, that I am now "moving" the speaker in one direction only. There are whole amplifier circuits I could use, but for this simple beeper I wanted a simple solution.
I can use H-BRIDGE to drive the speaker in two directions. But unlike when driving a motor, it would be more convenient to have one pin that creates the 0-5V wave, and another that decides if the speaker should be on or off.
I added an extra mosfet to normal H-BRIDGE and it works, but I won der if the number of mosfets can be reduced. Here is the circuit in a simulator, including a relative comparison to what it looks when just driving with a logic pin: https://tinyurl.com/29ebbpzs
Can a simpler version be done that acomplishes the same thing? That is, tone generated by square wave, on off by separate pin?
Note that the resistance and inductance of the speaker are made up, I was just testing if I can make it work at all.


To simplify your circuit while keeping the two-pin control of the speaker, you can use two MOSFETs in a simpler Half-Bridge configuration (push-pull). One MOSFET would pull the speaker up to 5V and the other would pull it down to 0V. This will achieve a similar effect to an H-bridge but with fewer components If you want to keep the square wave from the Arduino's tone function on one pin, you can add an enable/disable function using another MOSFET or transistor. This could be as simple as placing a MOSFET in series with the speaker and then using the second pin to control whether the speaker is connected to the output of the tone pin.

Could you please provide some example or a drawing? I am very new to electronics.

The tone pin (Pin 1) from the Arduino would drive the gate of a high-side MOSFET (MOSFET 1), which alternates between 0V and 5V, producing a square wave for the speaker. The low-side MOSFET (MOSFET 2) would have its gate connected to a second pin (Pin 2) that controls whether the speaker is on or off. The speaker is placed between the drains of the two MOSFETs, with the source of MOSFET 1 connected to 5V while the source of MOSFET 2 connected to ground. The tone pin handles audio signal and the second pin enable/disables the speaker by controlling the ground connection through low-side MOSFET.

Ah, I see. But that's what I am already doing. The point of this question, and the circuit I have shown, is to drive the speaker "in both directions", meaning when "tone pin" is HIGH current flows one way and when its low, it flows the other way. H-BRIDGE like in the image does that, but my solution needs 5 mosfets.
